# Problems while creating different page views in a single HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a basic html document which has three different views in a single document. The document, should allow you to go to the next view (page 2 and page 3) if you press the next button.

In particular, in page 2, the button is blocked until you check all the radios, then the document will allow you to continue next:

```js
function show(shown, hidden) {

    document.getElementById(shown).style.display = 'block';

    document.getElementById(hidden).style.display = 'none';

    document.querySelector('[data-testid="crowd-submit"]').style.display = 'inline-block';
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    return false;
}

function enableButton() {

    if (document.querySelectorAll("input[type^=radio]:checked").length === document.querySelectorAll("#Page1 .container").length) {
        document.getElementById('button').disabled = false;
    }
}
```

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .row h3 {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: solid;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .5rem 0;
    border-width: 1px
  }
  
  .row .layout-one div,
  .row .layout-two div {
    padding: .5rem;
  }
  
  .layout-one,
  .layout-two {
    border: .1rem solid #000;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    flex: 1;
    margin: 0 1rem;
  }
  
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  [data-testid="crowd-submit"] {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .border {
    border: 2px blue dashed;
  }
  
  .mr-0 {}
  
  .ml-auto {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  
  .d-block {
    display: block;
  }
  
  h4 {
    margin: 20px;
  }
  
  input[type=radio] {
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .details,
  .summary {
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: black;
    background: #D3D3D3;
    display: True;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://assets.crowd.aws/crowd-html-elements.js"></script>




<!-- For the full list of available Crowd HTML Elements and their input/output documentation,
please refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-ui-template-reference.html -->

<!-- You must include crowd-form so that your task submits answers to MTurk -->


<crowd-form answer-format="flatten-objects">
   <!-- Page 1 start -->
   <div id="Page1">
      <h3>Part 1/3</h3>
      <button type="button" id="button1" onclick="return show('Page2');">go to page 2</button>
   </div>
   <!-- Page 1 end -->
   <!-- Page 2 start -->
   <div id="Page2" style="display:none">
      <h3>Part 2/3</h3>
      <div class="container">
         <h4> question 2?</h4>
         <input type="radio" value="val1" name="question1_2_{{e[0]}}" required onclick="enableButton()">A</input>
         <input type="radio" value="val2" name="question1_2_{{e[0]}}" required onclick="enableButton()">B</input>
         <i></i>
      </div>
      <button type="button" id="button2" disabled onclick="return show('Page3');"><b>Go to page 3</b></button>
   </div>
   <!-- Page 2 end -->
   <!-- Page 3 start -->
   <div id="Page3" style="display:none">
      <h3>Part 3/3</h3>
      <div class="container">
         <h4>question 3?</h4>
         <input type="radio" value="val1" name="question1_3_{{e[0]}}" required onclick="enableButton()">X</input>
         <input type="radio" value="val2" name="question1_3_{{e[0]}}" required onclick="enableButton()">Y</input>
         <i></i>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- Page 3 end -->
</crowd-form>
```

The problem with the above document is that only the first page is working (i.e, from page 1 you can go to page 2). If you want to go from page 2 to page 3 the document doesnt work because `(a)` in page two the next button continue being disabled even if you check the radio, and `(b)` the submit button is not hiden (it should be visible only in page 3). Any idea about how to solve issues `(a)`, and `(b)`?

**Overall the expected behavior should be:**

**Page 1:** a normal next button that take you to Page 2, while hiding the submit button.

**Page 2:** a disabled next button, that only let you go to Page 3, if you only checked or answered all the radios in that view.

**Page 3:** Display only the submit button (orange)

So far I tried to:

Setting the display as: `style="display:none"`, and disable the button in page two, however, it is not working. Also, I tried to set the button behavior as `return show('Page3', 'Page2');`

Comment: Is it because these elements are in the shadow dom?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, yes I did it to hide the orange submit button, what is the logic, then to get the expected behavior? Thanks

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius even with that, the "go to page 3" button is not working as expected, any idea of how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code a bit. I just did not consider the return steps because you did not mention it.

```js
var pageNumber = 1;
function handlePage(button) {
    pageNumber = pageNumber + 1;
    button.innerText = "go to page " + (pageNumber + 1);
      
    document.getElementById('Page' + pageNumber).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('Page' + (pageNumber - 1)).style.display = 'none';
    
    switch(pageNumber)
    {
       case 1:
         break;
       case 2:
         document.getElementById('button1').disabled  = true;
         break;
       case 3:
         document.getElementById('button1').disabled  = true;
         document.getElementById('button1').style.display  = 'none';
         document.querySelector('[data-testid="crowd-submit"]').style.display = 'inline-block';
         break;
    }
     if(pageNumber >= 3)
       pageNumber = pageNumber - 1;
   
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    return false;
}
function enableButton() {
     document.getElementById('button1').disabled = false;
}
```

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .row h3 {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: solid;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .5rem 0;
    border-width: 1px
  }
  
  .row .layout-one div,
  .row .layout-two div {
    padding: .5rem;
  }
  
  .layout-one,
  .layout-two {
    border: .1rem solid #000;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    flex: 1;
    margin: 0 1rem;
  }
  
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  [data-testid="crowd-submit"] {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .border {
    border: 2px blue dashed;
  }
  
  .mr-0 {}
  
  .ml-auto {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  
  .d-block {
    display: block;
  }
  
  h4 {
    margin: 20px;
  }
  
  input[type=radio] {
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .details,
  .summary {
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: black;
    background: #D3D3D3;
    display: True;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://assets.crowd.aws/crowd-html-elements.js"></script>




<!-- For the full list of available Crowd HTML Elements and their input/output documentation,
please refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-ui-template-reference.html -->

<!-- You must include crowd-form so that your task submits answers to MTurk -->


<crowd-form answer-format="flatten-objects">
   <!-- Page 1 start -->
   <div id="Page1">
      <h3>Part 1/3</h3>
   </div>
   <!-- Page 1 end -->
   <!-- Page 2 start -->
   <div id="Page2" style="display:none">
      <h3>Part 2/3</h3>
      <div class="container">
         <h4> question 2?</h4>
         <input type="radio" value="val1" name="question1_2_{{e[0]}}" required Onchange="enableButton()">A</input>
         <input type="radio" value="val2" name="question1_2_{{e[0]}}" required Onchange="enableButton()">B</input>
         <i></i>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- Page 2 end -->
   <!-- Page 3 start -->
   <div id="Page3" style="display:none">
      <h3>Part 3/3</h3>
      <div class="container">
         <h4>question 3?</h4>
         <input type="radio" value="val1" name="question1_3_{{e[0]}}" required Onchange="enableButton()">X</input>
         <input type="radio" value="val2" name="question1_3_{{e[0]}}" required Onchange="enableButton()">Y</input>
         <i></i>
      </div>
   </div>
    <button type="button" id="button1" onclick="return handlePage(this);">go to page 2</button>
   <!-- Page 3 end -->
</crowd-form>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is almost the correct behavior. The only issue, is that in `Page2` the orage submit button should be hidden. The submit button only exist in `Page3`. Any idea about how to hide it in `Page1` and `Page2`, and show it in `Page3`?

Comment: I modified the submit button. It is now displayed on page 3

Comment: Thanks, one last thing, why there is a type error in the fiddle? `  "message": "TypeError: document.myForm is undefined",`

Comment: There was an extra code in the script. I deleted it. There is no error now.

Comment: Oh it was the console, thanks for the help